# Hibernate has difficult with create table using MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm doing a school project in architecture client-server with JavaFX, Maven, Hibernate etc 
I have big problem with implementation alone Hibernate (without Spring). 
Im not sure that is problem with configuration, dependencies or MySQL :/

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?> <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"> <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>


        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/carrental</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>

        <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>

        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>

        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>


        <!-- List of mapping files -->
        <mapping class="model.User" />



    </session-factory> </hibernate-configuration>
```

model.User

```
package model;

import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer userId;
    private String login;
    private String passwordHash;
    private Role role = Role.USER;
    private String emailAddress;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String street;
    private String zipCode;
    private String city;
    private String country;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private Boolean isCompany; //false private person //true company
    private String NIP;// Taxpayer Identification Number (TIN) //need only if enity is company


    public enum Role {
        USER, EMPLOYEE, ADMIN;
    }

public User() {
}

//używane do logowania
public User(String login, String password) {
    this.login = login;
    this.passwordHash = hashPassword(password);
}

public User(String login, String password, Role role, String emailAddress, String firstName, String lastName, String street, String zipCode, String city, String country, String phoneNumber, Boolean isCompany, String NIP) {
    this(login,password);
    this.role = role;
    this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.street = street;
    this.zipCode = zipCode;
    this.city = city;
    this.country = country;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.isCompany = isCompany;
    this.NIP = NIP;
}


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public Integer getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public String getPasswordHash() {
        return passwordHash;
    }

    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public Boolean getCompany() {
        return isCompany;
    }

    public String getNIP() {
        return NIP;
    }


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    private static String hashPassword(String password) {

        try {
            MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            messageDigest.update(password.getBytes());
            return new String(messageDigest.digest());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

MainTest.java (simple main for hibernate tests)

```
package server;


import model.User;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class MainTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();

//        Session session = sf.openSession();
//        session.beginTransaction();
//        session.save(new User("stiuil06","password"));
//        session.getTransaction().commit();
//        session.close();

    }
}
```

Compilation error

```
C:\Utilities\Java\jdk-10\bin\java "-javaagent:C:\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=18004:C:\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "F:\IdeaProjects\CarRental — kopia\target\classes;C:\Users\artur\.m2\repository\com\sun\mail\javax.mail\1.6.1\javax.mail-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\artur\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.3.0.Final\hibernate-core-5.3.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\artur\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.2.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\artur\.m2\repository\javax\persistence\javax.persistence-api\2.2\javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar;C:\Users\artur\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.22.0-GA\javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\artur\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.8.0\byte-buddy-1.8.0.jar;C:\Users\artur\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\artur\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec\1.0.1.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\artur\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.0.3.Final\jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\artur\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.3.0\classmate-1.3.0.jar;C:\Users\artur\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\artur\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.0.3.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\artur\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\5.1.6\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar;C:\Users\artur\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-entitymanager\5.0.2.Final\hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\artur\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api\1.0.0.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\artur\.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-jta_1.1_spec\1.1.1\geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\artur\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.3.0\jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar;C:\Users\artur\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.3.0\jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar;C:\Users\artur\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.0\jaxb-runtime-2.3.0.jar;C:\Users\artur\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-core\2.3.0\jaxb-core-2.3.0.jar;C:\Users\artur\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.0\txw2-2.3.0.jar;C:\Users\artur\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.5\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.5.jar;C:\Users\artur\.m2\repository\org\jvnet\staxex\stax-ex\1.7.8\stax-ex-1.7.8.jar;C:\Users\artur\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\fastinfoset\FastInfoset\1.2.13\FastInfoset-1.2.13.jar;C:\Users\artur\.m2\repository\javax\activation\activation\1.1.1\activation-1.1.1.jar" server.MainTest
cze 09, 2018 8:34:38 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.0.Final}
cze 09, 2018 8:34:38 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector (file:/C:/Users/artur/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.0/jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
cze 09, 2018 8:34:39 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.3.Final}
cze 09, 2018 8:34:39 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
cze 09, 2018 8:34:39 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/carrental]
cze 09, 2018 8:34:39 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=root}
cze 09, 2018 8:34:39 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
cze 09, 2018 8:34:39 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 10 (min=1)
cze 09, 2018 8:34:39 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
cze 09, 2018 8:34:39 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
cze 09, 2018 8:34:40 PM org.hibernate.type.spi.TypeConfiguration$Scope setSessionFactory
WARN: HHH000233: Scoping types to session factory org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@5cf87cfd after already scoped org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@5cf87cfd
Hibernate: 
cze 09, 2018 8:34:40 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection

    create table hibernate_sequence (
       next_val bigint
    ) type=MyISAM
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@1caa9eb6] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
cze 09, 2018 8:34:40 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
Hibernate: 

WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "
    insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
    create table hibernate_sequence (
       next_val bigint
    ) type=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    create table hibernate_sequence (
       next_val bigint
    ) type=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at server.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:13)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=MyISAM' at line 3
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2536)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2465)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:734)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 13 more

cze 09, 2018 8:34:40 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "
    insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at server.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:13)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'carrental.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2536)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2465)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:734)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 13 more

Hibernate: 
cze 09, 2018 8:34:40 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException

    create table User (
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "
       userId integer not null,
    create table User (
        NIP varchar(255),
       userId integer not null,
        city varchar(255),
        NIP varchar(255),
        country varchar(255),
        city varchar(255),
        emailAddress varchar(255),
        country varchar(255),
        firstName varchar(255),
        emailAddress varchar(255),
        isCompany bit,
        firstName varchar(255),
        lastName varchar(255),
        login varchar(255),
        passwordHash varchar(255),
        isCompany bit,
        phoneNumber varchar(255),
        role integer,
        lastName varchar(255),
        street varchar(255),
        login varchar(255),
        zipCode varchar(255),
        passwordHash varchar(255),
        primary key (userId)
        phoneNumber varchar(255),
    ) type=MyISAM
        role integer,
        street varchar(255),
        zipCode varchar(255),
        primary key (userId)
    ) type=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    create table User (
       userId integer not null,
        NIP varchar(255),
        city varchar(255),
        country varchar(255),
        emailAddress varchar(255),
        firstName varchar(255),
        isCompany bit,
        lastName varchar(255),
        login varchar(255),
        passwordHash varchar(255),
        phoneNumber varchar(255),
        role integer,
        street varchar(255),
        zipCode varchar(255),
        primary key (userId)
    ) type=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at server.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:13)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=MyISAM' at line 17
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2536)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2465)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:734)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 13 more
```

Anyone have an idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 18):

Refer to this line in stacktrace:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'type=MyISAM' at line

This suggests that you are using an updated version of MySQL but using and old dialect.

Change

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
```

to

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
```

Comment: Thank you i need `MySQL8Dialect`  solved problem

Answer (score 5):

Your current `dialect` generates following

```
type=MyISAM
```

where it need to be changed to

```
ENGINE=MyISAM
```

in the create table query by Hibernate.

To acheive this you need to use **different** `dialects`. Because `MySQLDialect` is **old** although you use an updated version of `MySQL`.

Use either,

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
```

OR

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>
```

in the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file.

Now you can go ahead with the create query without any `dialect` **errors**.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem in Spring Boot Application.

I was using XAMP.

I fixed the issue by changing the Hibernate Dialect in **application.properties**

**From**

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

***To***

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add annotation on Id property and try
Of

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

And let the DateBase manage the incrementation of the primary key:

AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the error "Error executing DDL `"create table hibernate_sequence (next_val bigint) type=MyISAM"` via JDBC Statement"

I changed `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect` to `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect` and it worked